# There is an error when compiling a c file used a nested function

Tags: c, gcc, clang, nested-function

I have known nested functions are supported as an extension in gcc, but I compile a c file used nested function with an error.
Error massage is like this:

> test.cpp:6:40: error: function definition is not allowed here   double
>
> ```
> square (double z) { return z * z; }
> ```

And nested function is like this:

```
foo (double a, double b)
 {
  double square (double z) { return z * z; }
  return square (a) + square (b);
 }
```

My operation system is Mac Os, and version is 10.12.6

When I enter `gcc -v` in iTerm2, the response is this:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition: *"Unlike function declaration, function definitions are allowed at file scope only (there are no nested functions)."*

Comment: clang doesn't support nested functions you need gcc.

Comment: Apple's "gcc" is just an alias for `clang`.

Comment: did you use `-std=gnu11` in your compilation statement? is it `gcc`, at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if the marked dupe is the most correct one, but it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually using using [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), not `gcc`.

Notice this

> `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)`

From [the clang website](https://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html), *Clang vs GCC (GNU Compiler Collection)*

> GCC supports many language extensions, some of which are not implemented by Clang. For instance, in C mode, GCC supports nested functions and has an extension allowing VLAs in structs.

Comment: Thx you all.I have just started to contact c.